# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException when trying to clone GIT on MAC

Tags: java, git, macos, ssl, visual-studio-code

When trying to clone a VSTS project repo to my Mac (via VS Code Terminal) I get the following certificate error

`git clone https://abc-masked.visualstudio.com/Test/_git/Test.UI`

```
Cloning into 'Test.UI'...
Configuration::loadGitConfiguration
Program::loadOperationArguments
Configuration::tryGetEntry
Configuration::tryGetEntry
Configuration::tryGetEntry
Configuration::tryGetEntry
Configuration::tryGetEntry
Configuration::tryGetEntry
Program::EnableTraceLogging
Program::get
   targetUri = https://abc-masked.visualstudio.com/
Program::ComponentFactory::createSecureStore
Getting a persistent token store that must be secure
Getting a persistent credential store that must be secure
Program::createAuthentication
   detecting authority type
BaseVsoAuthentication::getAuthentication
BaseVsoAuthentication::detectAuthority
   detected visualstudio.com, checking AAD vs MSA
Fatal error encountered.  Details:
java.lang.Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.microsoft.alm.authentication.BaseVsoAuthentication.detectAuthority(BaseVsoAuthentication.java:293)
    at com.microsoft.alm.authentication.BaseVsoAuthentication.getAuthentication(BaseVsoAuthentication.java:324)
    at com.microsoft.alm.gitcredentialmanager.Program.createAuthentication(Program.java:915)
    at com.microsoft.alm.gitcredentialmanager.Program$ComponentFactory.createAuthentication(Program.java:1174)
    at com.microsoft.alm.gitcredentialmanager.Program.initialize(Program.java:883)
    at com.microsoft.alm.gitcredentialmanager.Program.get(Program.java:292)
    at com.microsoft.alm.gitcredentialmanager.Program.access$200(Program.java:63)
    at com.microsoft.alm.gitcredentialmanager.Program$3.call(Program.java:284)
    at com.microsoft.alm.gitcredentialmanager.Program$3.call(Program.java:281)
    at com.microsoft.alm.gitcredentialmanager.Program.innerMain(Program.java:195)
    at com.microsoft.alm.gitcredentialmanager.Program.main(Program.java:123)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1329)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1204)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1151)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:178)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:163)
    at com.microsoft.alm.helpers.HttpClient.head(HttpClient.java:97)
    at com.microsoft.alm.authentication.BaseVsoAuthentication.detectAuthority(BaseVsoAuthentication.java:277)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:290)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:221)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1313)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 31 more
fatal: credential helper '!java -Ddebug=true -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -jar /usr/local/Cellar/git-credential-manager/2.0.4/libexec/git-credential-manager-2.0.4.jar' told us to quit
```

I have tried the following:

1. Updated the Java version
2. I downloaded the certificate from my VSTS domain (abc-masked.visualstudio.com) and added it to the Java keystore but that did not help.

   Also, I have git-credential-manager installed.

I am new to git, Can you please point me in the right direction?

Edit: This URL `https://abc-masked.visualstudio.com/` when I open in the browser immediately redirects to `https://dev.azure.com/abc-masked`.So I added both `*.dev.azure.com` and `*.visualstudio.com` certs to both Mac keychain and Java Keystore

Comment: Error says that "I cannot find all the necessary certificates and thus cannot trust this site" -> one or more certificates from the trust chain is missing or cannot be loaded. Check for solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Comment: @Jokkeri: I did check the thread but I am on Mac and I have already added the cert to the -keystore cacerts. Anything else that I need to verify here..?

Comment: It could be that you have only added the actual server cert but you are missing the CA certs from the truststore. It could be that java doesn’t recognize the root certificate authority (CA). Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12524960/2996452

Comment: I added the CA cert, but still the same error. Added the certs to Mac keychain as well but noting seem to work

Comment: I don't get it, why exactly is it running Java when you run a git command?

Answer (score 0):

Virtually, you have to trust the certificate. Get trusted certificate to clone a repo. You can refer my github url, I am doing exactly the same to clone a repo.

https://github.com/debjava/ddlab-gitpusher-idea/blob/master/ddlab.gitpusher.core/src/main/java/com/ddlab/gitpusher/util/HTTPUtil.java

Comment: You have to do programmatically to trust all. Just go through the github code link which I shared. If possible, share your code so that I can check.

Comment: Well there is no code, I am trying to clone git from Mac terminal as mentioned in the question